# SecurityContext.Current not working, nullexception

Tags: wcf, security, authentication

im using a WCF service with the users and roles being kept in the database. In my service im trying to identify whose calling the service. So i type in my WCF service

string user = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;

but i get i nullexception object not sent to an reference, ive tried googleing it all day but cant seem to find whats wrong. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please show your code and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

"What's wrong" is that `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` is returning `null` rather than an instance of `ServiceSecurityContext`.

One scenario where this occurs is if the binding is configured to use Message security with `MessageCredentialType` set to `None`.

However, I'm not aware of any comprehensive documentation listing every scenario where `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` can be `null`: as the security context is established in the channel stack it is something which depends on the specific binding configuration and security providers in use. It could also, I imagine, be affected by custom Behaviors which fiddle with message properties.

Having said that, unless you have custom code inserted into the channel stack, it is probably a safe assumption that this will only occur in cases where the binding does not require any client authentication. You should check first of all that you are using a binding configuration which will auhenticate the client and provide the kind of user name `IIdentity` you are expecting.